# How to get architecture of a shared object file(.so file) using gnu c++ program?

Tags: c++, linux

I have to create a c++ program to find out the whether the *.so(shared object) file is 32 bit or 64 bit (ex, libjvm.so). I did the same for dll files in windows, but got stuck on non-windows shared object file.

There are many commands available in Linux to find this out. But i don't see a simple programmatic ways to get this. The command objdump source code is having so many stuffs, not sure i can replicate it in my code.

I don't want to call the commands using system("") function inside my code, to get the architecture details.

Any idea how to get the architecture of .so file using gnu c++ program.

I am using Linux RHEl 6.2 and Compiler GNU gcc 4.8.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Read about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format and [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html). Then, just read the ELF header and process it.

Perhaps use [`libelf`](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) (or even [`libbfd`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/bfd/), which is overkill in your case) but you probably don't even need it, you could use `fread` on some `ElfN_Ehdr` and use `e_machine` and `e_type` from the ELF header.

Of course you might load the shared object with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), but that does run some (constructor, it may be a [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) code from the loaded plugin. Then use [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) but beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Answer (score 2):

In openSUSE 42.3 `objdump -f <your.so>` and you will get something like:

```
<your.so>:    file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x00003a80
```